# Laravel 5.4 - get translations from database instead of lang files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I need to keep my translations in a database. 
I have created a model with group, key and value and filled the database with all the values i currently have in my lang files. Now i wish to make the switch so if trans('group.key') or @lang('group.key') is called from my code i want it to get the value from database, not the lang file. How is it possible to achieve this?

PS. I looked through some of the available plugins that do something similar, but they dont quite fit me because i have my own complex models.

Comment: Do you have to use the built-in laravel `trans` and `@lang`? You could always write your own functions. Otherwise you would have to find and overwrite / extend the built in functions.

Comment: Natively, there isn't a way to specify that you want your translations to come from a DB vs `resources/lang/{code}`. Defining a `Model` for translations could work, just be aware of the inherent performance hits that will come from querying your DB for translations (especially since they're likely all strings)

Comment: Maybe you could generate your language files from your database each time you modify them, but it depends on how much you update them I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `Illuminate\Translation\Translator` class and pass in a collection from the database as an array in place of `$locale`. The `trans` function is just a wrapper for this class.

That class uses all the common support classes when working with arrays, collections, etc.

`use Countable;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;`